# PowerPivot: How to identify Max Value per Group in a Calculated Column

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I am building a data model within Power Pivot for Excel 2013 and need to be able to identify the max value within a column for a particular group. Unfortunately what I thought would work and what I have searched for previously gave me an error or wasn't applicable (there was a similar question that dealt with calculated measures rather than columns and wasn't replicable in Power Pivot data view to the best of my knowledge)

I have included an indication of what I am trying to achieve below, in this case I am trying to calculate the Max % uptake column.

```
Group | % uptake | Max % uptake            

A            40          45      
A            22          45                        
A            45          45                       
B            12          33                       
B            18          33                                   
B            33          33                       
C            3           16                       
C            16          16                                  
C            9           16
```

---

Many thanks

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
=CALCULATE(MAX([UPTAKE]),FILTER(Table1,[GROUP]=EARLIER([GROUP])))
```

Comment: This worked great and introduced me to the hugely useful EARLIER function which I will continue to use extensively in this project. Many thanks. Although, replace "{" with "[" to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

use this formula in cell ("C2"):

```
=MAX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B",MATCH(A2,$A$1:$A$10,0),":B",SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$1:$A$10=A2)*(ROW($A$1:$A$10)))))))
```

Comment: Hi Mohammed, I appreciate your response but it seems this catered towards Excel and not Power Pivot, thanks anyway though.