# Maximum value of a dynamic range

Tags: excel

I have a column with values. I want to find the maximum value of the minimum value of a 10 row deep range. So the first range would be a1:a10, the second range a2:a11 etc.  For each range the minimum value has to be calculated but not stored or displayed.  Then I need the maximum value of these minimum values. I do not need the minimum values by themselves, I only need the maximum value. 
I created the following array formula
{=MAX(MIN(OFFSET($C$10,$A$11:$A$366,1,10,1)))} which returns 0 although when using the array formula {=MIN(OFFSET($C$10,$A$11:$A$366,1,10,1))} in the range B11:B366 and applying max(B11:B366) I obtain the correct value.

I do not want to create the extra columns (which solves the problem) because these minimum values are of no interest, I only need to know the maximum of these 356 minimum values.

Thanks in advance,
Filiep

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would create a VBA function `MaxMin10(r As Range)` which you would use like the `Sum()` function.

Comment: check the below link 
[max value per group][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384258/powerpivot-how-to-identify-max-value-per-group-in-a-calculated-column/28387494#28387494

Answer (score 0):

I've a suspicion that there should be some logical shortcut to your query. However, for data in A1:A100:

`=MAX(SUBTOTAL(5,OFFSET(A1,MMULT(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,91))-1,1),,10)))`

I trust you can amend this to suit your actual needs? The 91 represents the fact that the last 10-cell range to be queried here would be A91:A100.

***Notes:*** The use of the MMULT function here is actually quite superfluous. In fact, it was used merely in order to coerce the required array of returns from the ROW construction, a coercion which would otherwise require that the formula be committed as an array formula, i.e. with CSE.

This rather artificial coercion can also be achieved in many cases using INDEX. However, it could be argued that such methods are not examples of best practice, and I probably shouldn't have employed such a technique here. After all, there's nothing whatsoever "wrong" with array formulas.

Having said that, here the extra function call will most likely mean that it is only a very small fraction less efficient than the equivalent CSE formula.

Anyway, this part:

`ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,91))-1`

generates an array of integers from 0 to 90, viz:

`ROW(A1:A91))-1`

i.e.:

`{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50;51;52;53;54;55;56;57;58;59;60;61;62;63;64;65;66;67;68;69;70;71;72;73;74;75;76;77;78;79;80;81;82;83;84;85;86;87;88;89;90;91}-1`

i.e.:

`{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50;51;52;53;54;55;56;57;58;59;60;61;62;63;64;65;66;67;68;69;70;71;72;73;74;75;76;77;78;79;80;81;82;83;84;85;86;87;88;89;90}`

the MMULT, as I said, lending the necessary array coercion. In fact, that's all it does, since:

`MMULT(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,91))-1,1)`

which is:

`MMULT({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50;51;52;53;54;55;56;57;58;59;60;61;62;63;64;65;66;67;68;69;70;71;72;73;74;75;76;77;78;79;80;81;82;83;84;85;86;87;88;89;90},1)`

is simply:

`{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50;51;52;53;54;55;56;57;58;59;60;61;62;63;64;65;66;67;68;69;70;71;72;73;74;75;76;77;78;79;80;81;82;83;84;85;86;87;88;89;90}`

though note that, without this additional function, or CSE-entry, the ROW construction:

`ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,91))`

would not resolve to an array (in fact it would return just the first element from the resulting array, i.e. 1).

This array is then passed to OFFSET as the *rows* parameter, which, with a *height* parameter of 10, means that we will generate an array of ranges to pass to SUBTOTAL, so that:

`OFFSET(A1,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,91))-1,,10)`

which is:

`OFFSET(A1,{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50;51;52;53;54;55;56;57;58;59;60;61;62;63;64;65;66;67;68;69;70;71;72;73;74;75;76;77;78;79;80;81;82;83;84;85;86;87;88;89;90},,10)`

is, effectively:

`{A1:A10;A2:A11;A3:A12;A4:A13;A5:A14;A6:A15;A7:A16;A8:A17;A9:A18;A10:A19;A11:A20;A12:A21;A13:A22;A14:A23;A15:A24;A16:A25;A17:A26;A18:A27;A19:A28;A20:A29;A21:A30;A22:A31;A23:A32;A24:A33;A25:A34;A26:A35;A27:A36;A28:A37;A29:A38;A30:A39;A31:A40;A32:A41;A33:A42;A34:A43;A35:A44;A36:A45;A37:A46;A38:A47;A39:A48;A40:A49;A41:A50;A42:A51;A43:A52;A44:A53;A45:A54;A46:A55;A47:A56;A48:A57;A49:A58;A50:A59;A51:A60;A52:A61;A53:A62;A54:A63;A55:A64;A56:A65;A57:A66;A58:A67;A59:A68;A60:A69;A61:A70;A62:A71;A63:A72;A64:A73;A65:A74;A66:A75;A67:A76;A68:A77;A69:A78;A70:A79;A71:A80;A72:A81;A73:A82;A74:A83;A75:A84;A76:A85;A77:A86;A78:A87;A79:A88;A80:A89;A81:A90;A82:A91;A83:A92;A84:A93;A85:A94;A86:A95;A87:A96;A88:A97;A89:A98;A90:A99;A91:A100}`

which array of range references we then pass to SUBTOTAL, with a *function_num* parameter of 5 (i.e. MIN), which results in an array of values comprising the minimum value from each of the above arrays, e.g.:

`{10;10;13;11;11;11;11;11;11;11;11;11;11;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;30;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;24;24;12;12;12;12;12;6;6;6;6;6;6;6;6;6;6;7;7;7;7;7;7;7;7;18;8;8;8;8;8;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;7;7;7;7;7;7;7;7}`

which is then finally passed to MAX.

Regards

Comment: Thank you but I don't see how the subtotal will generate the minimum value for my 10 consecutive rows

Comment: You mean that you don't understand how this combination of functions operates? Or that you tried the formula and it did not give you the desired results? If so, did you first test the formula on a dataset in A1:A100? What results did you get? And, assuming you were able to amend the ranges to suit your actual needs, what results did you get then? Why were they not what were you expecting?

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution does work; exactly what I wanted.  I just could not understand how your formula through the subtotal and mmult could derive the minimum value.  Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, ok. You're welcome. If you want I can add some words of explanation into my post. though the construction employed is not a straightforward one, so I couldn't promise that it will be easy to understand, even after I've presented a deconstruction.

Comment: If you could provide the extra information that would be helpful, not only for me but also for other subscribers to this forum.  I will take a chance if the deconstruction is not easy. I greatly appreciate your help and experience. Kind Regards. Filiep

Comment: Thank you very much for expanding my Excel knowledge.  Your answer was very detailed and easy to follow.  Your effort in helping me with this problem is very well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For data in `A1:A30` cells you could use following formula:

```
=MAX(SUBTOTAL(5,OFFSET((A1:A21),ROW(A1:A21)-1,,10)))
```

The `-1` parameter should be changed to the starting row number

EDIT: as @XOR LX commented below, this is an array formula, so you need to confirm it using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`

Comment: Perhaps worth letting the OP know that this is an array formula? They may not necessarily know that just from looking at it, nor what in fact an array formula is?

Comment: @XOR LX Yes, thank you, I will edit the answer. There was an array formula in the question, so I forgot to add a note about it.

Comment: Ah! Good point. You're right - and I guess it won't really be necessary in that case.

Answer (score 0):

A VBA solution that can be used as a user designed function on the sheet:

```
=LargestMinimum(A1:A365)
```

VBA code:

```
Function LargestMinimum(rng As Range) As Integer
    Dim i As Long, max As Integer, col As Integer, temp As Integer

    res = 0
    col = rng.Column

        For i = 1 To rng.Count - 9
            temp = WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(Cells(i, col), Cells(i + 9, col)))
            res = IIf(temp > res, temp, res)
        Next i

    LargestMinimum = res
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you but I wanted to do this without using VBA